# CSS Image is misplaced

Tags: css

I have two divs. One with an image and one below with a background (semitranparent) and a text. The last div I give the css margin-top: -25px to make an overlap.
But the image in the first div is placed in between the semitranparent background and the text of the last div.

```
div.polaroid {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

div.container {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
<div class="polaroid">
<img src="http://originalen.com/fileadmin/user_upload/skov.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%">
<div class="container">
  <p>The Troll's tongue in Hardanger, Norway</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Donslund/bsdk804p/1/

Comment: You never closed the first div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div.polaroid {
  position:relative;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  z-index:1;
}

div.container {
  position:relative;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -37px;
  z-index:5;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="polaroid">
<img src="http://originalen.com/fileadmin/user_upload/skov.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%">

<div class="container">
  <p>The Troll's tongue in Hardanger, Norway</p>
</div>
    </div>
```

Here it overlaps like you wanted (I assume).

Comment: In my Google Chrome, the semi red is still behind the image in your code.

Comment: I had misplaced the ending part of the div. If you check it now it should be good

Comment: You want the text just in the red section? add " div.polaroid img{ margin-bottom: 20px;" Or what is the issue?